# Почему ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, при сортирвке массива?

Tags: javascript

Почему код не выводит массив? Пишет:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on line 4

```js
let arr = [25, 8, 7, 41];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
 return (a — b);
})
alert(arr);
```

Comment: let arr = [25,8,7,41].sort((a,b)=> a-b)
alert(arr) попробуйте так

Comment: Потому что минус какой-то длинный.

Comment: @Qwertiy копировал с сайта)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас стоит другой символ вместо минуса.

```js
    let arr = [25, 8, 7, 41];
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a - b);
    });
    alert(arr);
```